# Unable to solve for variables with subscripts

Tags: equation-solving, subscript, notation

```
ΔF = 0.0025;
Subscript[R, s] = Quantity[0.8, "SolarRadius"];
P = Quantity[8, "Days"];
```

When I solve for `Rp` all works great:

```
Subscript[R, s] = Quantity[0.8, "SolarRadius"];
ΔF = 0.0025; (*Transit depth*)
Solve[{Rp^2/Subscript[R, s]^2 == ΔF, Rp > 0}, Rp, Reals ]
```

but when I solve for a variable with a subscript (`Subscript[R, p]` instead of `Rp`), Mathematica finds no solution:

```
Subscript[R, s] = Quantity[0.8, "SolarRadius"];
ΔF = 0.0025; (*Transit depth*)
Solve[
  {Subscript[R, p]^2/Subscript[R, s]^2 == ΔF, Subscript[R, p] > 0}, 
  Subscript[R, p], Reals ]
```

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this and treat variables with subscript as normal (separate) variable names?

Interestingly, Mathematica seems to have no problem when, for example, `a` is given a subscript. It's only an issue when the variable that I solve for has a subscript.

Comment: With 11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 27, 2017) everything works as expected

Comment: Don't use subscripts, you will be better of with regular variables.

Comment: Edit: added a definition for P. Apparently this seems to interfere. But not clear why P, and Subscript[R,p] are not treated separately

Comment: Works as expected in 12.1 on Windows.

Comment: I have to agree with yarchik though. Don't use subscripts, or at least only use them for display purposes. You'll find the same advice in many questions on this site. A `Subscript` expression is not a `Symbol` and there are lots of parts of the language which don't work properly when you use subscripts instead of symbols for your variables.

Comment: restarting Mathematica 12.0 seems to have solved the problem. But still very odd behavior.

Comment: Good practice is to avoid variable that start with capital letter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem the OP is experiencing cannot be reproduced; I suspect it is being caused by corrupted lexical elements in the OP's Mathematica notebook.